# Get array values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of `topics`. Some of them contain `parent` or `child` topics. I want to echo each topic even if it is a child. I loop through the array of topics, then check if the topic value is an array. If yes, then again loop through it and assign the topic to the `topicName` variable. If no, then assign the topic to the variable without looping. However, when I echo `topicName` it only echoes the ones in the else statement and it doesn't echo all of the topics. Can someone explain to me why it doesn't?

```
<?php
  $topics = [
            'Opening',
            'Aanwezigen',
            'Opmerkingen vorige notulen',
            'Ingezonden stukken' => [
                'Jaarverslag 2019',
                'Jaarcijfers 2019',
            ],
            'Jaarrekening 2019' => [
                'Voorstel tot vaststelling van de jaarcijfers 2019 (stempunt)',
                'Vaststelling dividenduitkering (stempunt)',
                'Bespreking reserverings- en dividendbeleid',
            ],
            'Rondvraag',
            'Afsluiting',
        ];


foreach ($topics as $topic) {
    if (is_array($topic)) { 
        for($i = 0; $i < count($topic); $i++) {
            $topicName = $topic[$i];
        }
    } else {
        $topicName = $topic;
    }

    echo $topicName;    
}
?>
```

Comment: Does only 1 check of `if (is_array($topic))` get you everything? Wouldn't it be nested many levels deep?

Comment: Yes this gives me all the values that are childs @vivek_23

Comment: Because your current `$topics` is only 2 levels deep. What if it becomes more than `2`?

Comment: Then I probably won't get all the values @vivek_23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it recursive for it to work for any levels deep.

```
function recursivelyPrintTopicNames($topics){
    foreach ($topics as $topic => $child_topic) {
        if (is_array($child_topic)) { 
           echo $topic,PHP_EOL;    // print parent topic here itself
           recursivelyPrintTopicNames($child_topic);
        } else {
            echo $child_topic,PHP_EOL;    
        }
    }
}

recursivelyPrintTopicNames($topics);
```

- We check if current value is an array, if yes, then the key is a parent topic. We recursively call the same function to print further child topics.
- If current value isn't an array, it's just a topic with no children.

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/WoSJq

Answer (score 2):

When you pass in the foreach, you overwrite with the last element so the topicName is always the last element of the array (Jaarcijfers 2019 and Bespreking reserverings- en dividendbeleid BUT other in array where not displayed : 'Voorstel tot vaststelling van de jaarcijfers 2019 (stempunt)', 'Vaststelling dividenduitkering (stempunt)', TopicName should be an array in this case.

```
<?php

    $topics = [
                'Opening',
                'Aanwezigen',
                'Opmerkingen vorige notulen',
                'Ingezonden stukken' => [
                    'Jaarverslag 2019',
                    'Jaarcijfers 2019',
                ],
                'Jaarrekening 2019' => [
                    'Voorstel tot vaststelling van de jaarcijfers 2019 (stempunt)',
                    'Vaststelling dividenduitkering (stempunt)',
                    'Bespreking reserverings- en dividendbeleid',
                ],
                'Rondvraag',
                'Afsluiting',
            ];


    $mineTopics = [];

    foreach ($topics as $key => $topic) {
        if (is_array($topic)) { 
            // Add key 
            $mineTopics[] = $key;
            for($i = 0; $i < count($topic); $i++) {
                $mineTopics[] = $topic[$i];
            }
        } else {
            $mineTopics[] = $topic;
        }
    }

    var_dump($mineTopics);
```

EDIT:

Capture the key in the foreach loop and add it to your final array

Comment: I already tried this solution, but result is not complete, `Ingezonden stukken'` and `Jaarrekening 2019` missed :)

Comment: Works only for 2 levels?